# Making multiple text input fields look combined with float property (css, bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style login input fields like the following
and I got the desired outcome from inspecting the live elements
but I don't quite understand the usage of `float` property here.

[image]

Using Bootstrap, this is how the html looks

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrap-input">
        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input">
        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="password"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn">test</button>
```

Here I have `wrapper` with `float: left` and nesting `wrap-input` that also has `float: left`.

Can someone please explain why `float` is necessary here to achieve this?

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/zVqE2/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap-input is floated so that it sticks to each other. 
Next the element is being displayed block so that it can be set a width;
The author then set the width of the wrap-input to be 100%. That means the width 
of wrapper. So there is no space for wrap-inputs to be on the same line 
so the second one just go to the next line.

Since they are floated they stick to each other. That is the whole concept.

Without float the heights and widths have to be set explicity and the margins too.

Answer (score 0):

I just eliminated both `float`'s, and you are still getting the basic look and feel you are looking for, at least in Chrome. See http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/zVqE2/5/ for a working example.

The only thing they seem to be doing is keeping the `input`'s from running the width of the page. That could easily be solved by either setting the `width` property on the `.wrapper` class, or just using one of Bootstrap's built-in classes (see the docs).